# Python http.client json request and response. How?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code that I'd like to update to Python 3.x
The required libraries would change to http.client and json.

I can't seem to understand how to do it. Can you please help?

```
import urllib2
import json


data = {"text": "Hello world github/linguist#1 **cool**, and #1!"}
json_data = json.dumps(data)

req = urllib2.Request("https://api.github.com/markdown")
result = urllib2.urlopen(req, json_data)

print '\n'.join(result.readlines())
```

Comment: related: [code examples how to make a https POST request using any of socket, httplib, urllib2, request modules on both Python 2 and 3](https://gist.github.com/1841962)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
import http.client
import json

connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection('api.github.com')

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

foo = {'text': 'Hello world github/linguist#1 **cool**, and #1!'}
json_foo = json.dumps(foo)

connection.request('POST', '/markdown', json_foo, headers)

response = connection.getresponse()
print(response.read().decode())
```

I will walk you through it. First you'll need to create a TCP connection that you will use to communicate with the remote server.

```
>>> connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection('api.github.com')
```

-- [`http.client.HTTPSConnection()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPSConnection)

Thẹ̣n you will need to specify the request headers.

```
>>> headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
```

In this case we're saying that the request body is of the type application/json.

Next we will generate the json data from a python dict()

```
>>> foo = {'text': 'Hello world github/linguist#1 **cool**, and #1!'}
>>> json_foo = json.dumps(foo)
```

Then we send an HTTP request to over the HTTPS connection.

```
>>> connection.request('POST', '/markdown', json_foo, headers)
```

Get the response and read it.

```
>>> response = connection.getresponse()
>>> response.read()
b'<p>Hello world github/linguist#1 <strong>cool</strong>, and #1!</p>'
```

Comment: note: ["If no Accept header field is present, then it is assumed that the client accepts all media types."](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.1). And it should be `'*/*'`, not `'*'`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I hesitated about it but did not bother to find out the details about it. Thank you for noticing.

Comment: Modify headers to "headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'Python 3 Script'}" in order to get past the Github requirement http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required

Comment: How do I get the response.read() into a variable or write it into a file ?

I get the error as "RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response."

Comment: @Sarang Run `body = response.read()` before you call `response.read()` in any other place. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects for more information.

Comment: This is the code i m running,

 `res = conn.getresponse(),
 data = res.read(),
 print(data.decode("utf-8"))`

Data gets printed correctly, But what I am not able to do is use this data or write it into a file.

Comment: @Sarang `open('myfile', 'wb').write(data)` or `open('myfile', 'w').write(data.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks  a ton. Can I get this value in a variable and iterate over in some manner ?

Answer (score 1):

To make your code Python 3 compatible it is enough to change import statements and encode/decode data assuming `utf-8` everywhere:

```py
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

data = {"text": "Hello world github/linguist№1 **cool**, and #1!"}
response = urlopen("https://api.github.com/markdown", json.dumps(data).encode())
print(response.read().decode())
```

See [another https post example](https://gist.github.com/1841962#file_http_post_urllib.py).

Answer (score -2):

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('https://api.github.com/markdown')
conn.request("GET", "/markdown")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print r1.read()
```

Comment: but where is the part where you are submitting the json encoded data to this url?

Comment: This is an incorrect response, it won't even succeed to initialize the `HTTPSConnection()`.

Comment: note: the OP wants POST request, not GET. And as @joar noted the first arg of HTTPSConnection should be host, not URL.