# Properly formatting http.client.HTTPSConnection in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Overall, I'm trying to invoke the MS Cognitive [key phrases API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c6/console) from Python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (32-bit). I looked everywhere and tried to incorporate this stackoverflow [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763976/python-http-client-json-request-and-response-how).

To call the API your account key below marked as ## needs to be added [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-US/subscriptions), 
however to format the body correctly you probably don't need the account key. A good portion of the code below is from sample code.

Request body should look like

```
body = {
  "documents": [
        {
            "language": "en",
            "id": "1",
            "text": "One line of text."
        },
        {
            "language": "en",
            "id": "2",
            "text": "another line of text."
        }
    ]
}
```

my code <**it now works!!**>

```
import sys
import os.path
import http.client
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
import base64
import json

subscription_key = '##'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key
}

#input text is: ID | text to analyze. How my input file is formatted.
input_text = ["100|One line of text.", "101|another line of text."]


# Inputs holds the params to call the web service in bulk.
body = []

indx = 1

for line in input_text:
    input_text = line.split("|")
    print ('-----\n')
    print ("Input text is:", input_text)
    input_text_analyze = input_text[1]
    print ('\nInput text to be analyzed:', input_text_analyze)
    body.append({ "language" : "en", "id" : str(indx), "text" : input_text_analyze })
    indx = indx + 1

print ('-----\n')
print ('\nBody has', body)

print ("Calling API to get keywords...")

body_documents = { 'documents': body }

print ("\nParams:", body_documents)

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({ })

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/text/analytics/v2.0/keyPhrases?%s" % params, str(body_documents), headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    keyword_obj = response.read()
    print("Returned keyword_obj is: ", keyword_obj)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made 2 changed to the code above that allow it to work. 1) I was getting my params and body mixed up. 2) I needed to add str(body_documents) in my post. Both beginner mistakes.